# Facebook.showPermissionDialog

Tags: facebook

Hello i'm trying to use facebook showPermissionDialog to get user datas

this is my code

```
function switch_menu(element, id) {

      var ajax = new Ajax();
      Facebook.showPermissionDialog('manage_pages,offline_access,email,publish_stream,user_photos,user_birthday')
      ajax.responseType = Ajax.FBML;
      ajax.ondone = function(data) {
        document.getElementById('topic_loading').setInnerFBML(data);
      }
      ajax.onerror = function() {}
      ajax.post('#{oauth_authorize_url(:canvas => false, :format => :js)}')
    }
```

The dialog is opening very well, my question is how to get the user data after that the user has accepted the conditions.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have already found the soln to this. Just in case here it is:

```
Facebook.showPermissionDialog("bla,bla,bla permissions", FacebookPermissionHandler);

function FacebookPermissionHandler(handler)
{
   new Dialog().showMessage('Okay.', ""+handler);
   //handler contains allowed permission(s) [comma seperated] from the user.
}
```

FB documentation actually explains this.

Please double check the documentation if you cant get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [bug in Facebook.showPermissionDialog()](http://www.appelsiini.net/2011/ajax-fails-after-showpermission-dialog) which causes Ajax requests silently fail after user gives you the permissions. Since you are already asking for extra permission you can set *ajax.requireLogin* to *false*. This should fix the Ajax request.

```
function switch_menu(element, id) {
    var ajax = new Ajax();
     Facebook.showPermissionDialog('manage_pages,offline_access,email,publish_stream,user_photos,user_birthday')
    ajax.responseType = Ajax.FBML;
    ajax.requireLogin = false;
    ajax.ondone = function(data) {
        document.getElementById('topic_loading').setInnerFBML(data);
    }
    ajax.onerror = function() {}
    ajax.post('#{oauth_authorize_url(:canvas => false, :format => :js)}')
}
```